# chef: ohai does not provide node['etc']

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I had a requirment to do a certain action only given that a specific user exists. Looking at the following question [Chef Users resource (check if exists?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094558/chef-users-resource-check-if-exists) I concluded that the following:

```
if node['etc']['passwd']['random']
```

would be a good method.

This actually worked when I tested it in kitchen, but when pushed to production this crushed on all servers with the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

When using ohai from bash I do see `etc: {...}`

What exactly is happening here?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't that `node['etc']['passwd']` isn't the part which isn't loading?

Comment: Yes. We ran `chef-shell -z` and `node['etc'] ` returned nil

Comment: Please test with actual `chef-client`, `chef-shell` can be unpredictable at best.

Comment: just ran it again with `node['etc']['passwd']` and it still fails. on etc being nil

Comment: Run `chef-client -l debug` and you should see debugging output from Ohai at the top. Check for anything related to the etc plugin. Also check you didn't disable the plugin in either the Chef or Ohai config files.

Comment: What is the OS, where Ohai can't find the `etc`?

Comment: Don't you have disabled etc plugin in client.rb ?

Comment: found these 2 lines: `# https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-5045`
`Ohai::Config[:disabled_plugins] << 'passwd' << :Passwd << :Filesystem2` . since the issue mentioned is still relevant, I ended up checking for the existence of a user like so: `if 'grep td-agent /etc/passwd > /dev/null; echo $?' == '0'`. It's ugly, but it works. Thank you all for the help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, with the help of the people in the comments, I have found that the Ohai passwd plugin was in fact disabled. Due to that, I had to work around the problem and query the existence of a user like so:

```
if 'grep td-agent /etc/passwd > /dev/null; echo $?' == '0'
```

Finally, for future reference, my entire resource:

```
group 'groupname' do
  action :create
  members 'td-agent' if 'grep td-agent /etc/passwd > /dev/null; echo $?' == '0'
  append true
end
```